# Why is my product detail not rendering in React when an id is passed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django-rest-framework, react-router, react-router-dom

My project returns an error of **undefined is not an object (evaluating 'product.title')** while I expect it to return the product's detail.

Please see my fixture below: **Fixture.js A**

```
        "id": 1,
        "images": [
            {
                "image": "/media/product-images/43c39863-3c9d-4229-a60f-a57c96fd3278.png"
            }
        ],
        "title": "Asus Zenbook",
        "image": null,
        "is_active": true,
        "bestseller": true,
        "flashsales": false,
        "toppicksforyou": false,
        "monthlysales": false,
        "bestdeals": true,
        "brand": "Asus",
        "sku": "1",
        "price": "1234.00",
        "old_price": "3333.00",
        "quantity": 3,
        "slug": "asus-zenbook",
        "meta_keywords": "Asus",
        "category": 1,
        "brands": []
    },
type here
```

ProductList.js

```
import { useState, useEffect, memo, useCallback } from "react";
const React = require('react')



import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  RouterProvider,
  Route,
  Link,
} from "react-router-dom";





function ProductList() {
  const products = useProduct(
    ({ state: { products } }) => products.map(({ id }) => id),
    true
  );
  if (products.length === 0) {
    return (
      <div className="product-list">
        <div className="text-center">There is no product to display</div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
     <div className="flex-wrapper">
      {products.map((product) => (
       <Product
       key={product} 
       id={product} 
     
       
     />
          
       
   

      ))}
    </div>
 
    
 
    
  );
}

export default memo(ProductList);
```

Product.js

```
const React = require('react')
import { useState, memo, Fragment, useMemo } from "react";


import useProduct from "./useProduct";

import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  RouterProvider,
  Route,
  Link,
} from "react-router-dom";



function Product({ id, }) {
  const { product, } = useProduct(
    ({
      state: { products },

    }) => ({
      product: products.find((product) => product.id === id),
    }),
    true
  );
 
  return (
    <div className='col-3'>
      <div className='card'>
      <Link to={`/products/${product.id}`}>

        <img
        
          src={`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/products${product.image}`}
          alt={product.quantity}
          className='card-img-top'
        />
      
        <div className='card-body'>
          <h3 className='card-title'>{product.title}</h3>
          <h3 className='card-title'>{product.price}</h3>
        </div>
           </Link>
      </div>
     
    </div>
 
  );
}




export default memo(Product);
```

Detail.js

```
import React from 'react';

import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import useProduct from './useProduct'



function Detail() {
  const {id} = useParams()
  const { product } = useProduct(
    ({
      state: { products },

    })=> ({
      product: products.find((product) => product.id === id),
    }),
    true
  );   
  console.log(id)
  return (
      <div>
          <h1>{product.title}</h1>
          <p>Price: ${product.price}</p>
          <p>{product.overview}</p>
      </div>
  )
}
export default Detail;
```

The id params are rendering correctly when I change the id **Fixture.js A** above to: (notice the double quotes "")

```
   {
        id: "1",
        ......

  
    },
```

I get product detail results as expected. The issue is that the Django REST API only returns results with id as shown in **Fixture A**

What could be the issue? Is it an issue with my DRF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `id` in the data is a number type, e.g. `"id": 1`, but the route path params are always a string type, e.g. `const { id } = useParams();` `id` will be a string. The issue is that you are using strict equality, i.e. `===`, which compares the types and if the two operands are different types they can never be equal. Because no element in the `products` array passes the predicate condition `array.find`returns undefined. You can't access `title` of undefined and an error is thrown. This is why the UI code works when you changed the `id` type in the data to a string, i.e. `id: "1"`, the types matched.

Test

```js
console.log('1 === "1"', 1 === "1"); // false
console.log("1 === 1", 1 === 1); // true
```

You can either use string-type `id` values in the JSON data

```json
id: "......"
```

Or use loose equality checks, e.g. `==` which will attempt a type coercion

```js
console.log('1 == "1"', 1 == "1"); // true
console.log("1 == 1", 1 == 1); // true
```

Or use a type-safe comparison by casting all values to same type. I suggest using string types as this covers all strings, including number-like string values.

```js
console.log('String(1) === "1"', String(1) === "1"); // true
console.log('String("1") === "1"', String("1") === "1"); // true
```

Also, because `Array.prototype.find` potentially returns undefined you should safe-guard the UI to prevent accidental undefined accesses. In other words, check first if there's actually a defined `product` value.

```js
function Detail() {
  const { id } = useParams();

  const product = useProduct(
    ({ state })=> state.products.find((product) => String(product.id) === id),
    true
  );

  if (!product) {
    return <div>No matching product found</div>;
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{product.title}</h1>
      <p>Price: ${product.price}</p>
      <p>{product.overview}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: That's right, @Drew Reese. I have been unsuccessfully trying to fix this issue for a week. I have been using React v18, which supports Router v6 and significantly differs from Router v5.  I value the effort and time you put into helping me.